# Chrome / Safari Inspector can't change onClick parameter

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, safari-web-inspector

Let's say I have a button with onClick attribute set to `doSomeThings(someId)`
When I inspect it on Chrome or Safari it shows:

```
<button onclick="doSomeThings("1")" type="button"> </button>
```

Now I use the Chrome / Safari inspector and change the 1 to, let's say, 3, and press enter. I don't get

```
<button onclick="doSomeThings("3")" type="button"> </button>
```

but

```
<button onclick="doSomeThings(" type="button"> </button>
```

Is it some security feature or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: It's a bug in devtools and you can report it on https://crbug.com. Meanwhile use single quotemarks like `'3'`